# Does the number of bins influence the "measures of similarity" among histograms?

Tags: probability, distributions, discrete-data, histogram, similarities

I have calculated several "measures of similarity" among histograms and discrete probability distributions (such as Cosine similarity, Kullback-Leibler divergence, Jensen-Shannon distance, Wasserstein distance, Hellinger distance, Székely dCorr, etc..).

It looks like, or better to say, I have observed, that the results of the "measures of similarity" change when the number of bins, composing the histograms - and the relative discrete probability distributions -, varies.

**Is the change of the measures' outputs an expected behavior/feature in Statistics when the number of bins, that compose the histograms - and the relative discrete probability distributions -, varies ?**"

**In other words, should the "measures of similarity" among histograms, and discrete probability distributions, be invariant under a bins number variation?**

Comment: Binning throws away detail in most cases, so whether and how you bin must have an influence on any of these measures. The limiting case is one bin in both cases and then the resemblance can be perfect.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NickCox. From your comment, I understand that the number of bins DOES influence the "measures of similarity" among histograms... :-) :-) That's reassuring, thanks a lot! If you want to write it in an Answer, I accept it.. :-)

Comment: Some "measures of similarity" or of divergence such as Wasserstein distance or the Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic do not need histograms at all and can even be used to compare a discrete distribution with a continuous distribution

Comment: I think histograms are a distraction from the real question, which I take to be about comparing distributions -- which should use the raw data as far as possible.